# Where / How get Training kits & MOCs for 50392A (Complete ASP.NET 3.5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I just wondering where to get the training kits and MOCs for the course 50392A (Complete ASP.NET 3.5) 
I searched a lot but nothing ..
I also tried to search for courses with the same material but nothing too .

Please recommend place where i can download the MOC from 
Or
Recommend another courses with the same content , even if more than one course

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will get the materials if you attend the course ... I don't think this is a good site to ask for "warez".

Comment: I am not asking for warez 
I just want to know how and where to get the materials

Comment: Those materials are simply not free. You have to pay for them when you attend the course. Even in that case I guess you will get only course book but you will not get labs (usually virtual machine for each lab).

Comment: Should I attend the course to take the MOC , How can i just buy it , as i am in a country where i can't find such course ??